# How do I run specific tests using dotnet test?

Tags: xunit.net, .net-core, .net-core-rc2, xunit2

I have a large test suite in a .NET Core project. I can use the Test Explorer window to select a few tests to run.

I can also run the **whole** test suite on the command line with `dotnet test`. Is there a way to run only one (or a few) tests on the command line?

Answer (score 127, accepted):

With the dotnet version 1.0.0, you have to use the --filter option:

You can filter by DisplayName, FullyQualifiedName and Traits.

Ex:

```
dotnet test --filter "FullyQualifiedName=YourNamespace.TestClass1.Test1"
```

Also, these operators are allowed: =, != and ~ (contains).

More info here: [docs](https://github.com/Microsoft/vstest-docs/blob/master/docs/filter.md)

Comment: I tried this out and this solution works also for the 1.1 version and a [Theory] decorated method. Switches `-method` and `-class` aren't available in 1.1 anymore and you'll get an error: `MSBUILD: error MSB1001: Unkown switch. Switch: -method`

Comment: Yep, I just confirmed this. `-method` no longer works, but `--filter` does. Thanks @andrecarlucci!

Comment: Since version 15.1 the expression can be a keyword that will be matched against the fully qualified names. As the documentation states "`dotnet test --filter xyz` is same as `dotnet test --filter FullyQualifiedName~xyz`" Which is much comfortable !

Answer (score 9):

Since this question is tagged with **xUnit**, the command for the dotnet xUnit CLI command is as follows:

```
dotnet xunit -method FullyQualifiedName
```

Comment: FYI: `dotnet xunit` is now retired. `dotnet test` is right CLI command (powered by the `xunit.runner.visualstudio` package).